# Ruby rails - form is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

To create a new user I use a search view to find user info in ldap and populate the data in the new user creation form. Then submitting that form will create a new user locally in mysql. So the new user create form is already populated and I can the values. But after submitting that form the page comes back with message saying the fields were blank. Not sure why is that. In http debug I see those values were posted to /users/new

```
Form is invalid

User can't be blank
Firstname can't be blank
Lastname can't be blank
Email can't be blank
Role can't be blank
```

Controller -

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def new
        @user = User.new
        @result = User.FindActiveDirectory(params[:user_id])
    if @result.empty?
        render action: 'find', message: "Could not find a user with the id #{params[:user_id]}"
else
    return @result

    end

  end

def find
end


def display_result

    @result = User.FindActiveDirectory(params[:user_id])
    if @result.empty?
        render action: 'find', message: "Could not find a user with the id #{params[:user_id]}"
    end
return @result
end


  def create

        @user = User.new(params[:user_id])
        if @user.save
                redirect_to users_added_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
        else
                render "new"
        end
  end

end
```

User view find (find.html.erb) -

```
<h1>find User </h1>
<p><%= notice %></p>

<%= form_tag users_new_path do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :Username %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :user_id %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= submit_tag " Search " %></p>
<% end %>
```

Users view create new (new.html.erb)-

```
<h1>Add user to access this system</h1>

<% if @result %>
<% @result.each do |key, values| %>
<% if "#{key}" == "samaccountname" %>
<% $username = values.to_s %>
<% end %>
<% if "#{key}" == "sn" %>
<% $lastname = values.to_s %>
<% end %>
<% if "#{key}" == "givenname" %>
<% $firstname = values.to_s %>
<% end %>
<% if "#{key}" == "mail" %>
<% $email = values.to_s %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>


<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :NT_Username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user_id, :value => $username  %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :Firstname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :firstname, :value => $firstname  %>
  </p>
 <p>
    <%= f.label :Lastname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lastname, :value => $lastname %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email, :value => $email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Role %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => false %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Request -

```
Started POST "/users" for 10.15.21.28 at 2012-04-07 00:00:17 -0400
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"RDxvWXxVwoJArNN1s4Q8M8cDr5rzjP4wNF4gOnteGGY=", "user"=>{"user_id"=>"jkills000", "firstname"=>"James", "lastname"=>"Kills", "email"=>"jkills000@mysite.com", "role"=>"User"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `create` you do:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user_id])
```

This is incorrect. It should be:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

As you can see in the request, `params[:user]` contains all the info about the user. `params[:user_id]` does not exist.

Comment: Great.. Thanks for super quick answer! somehow I changed it to user_id. It worked.